# Scrapy FormRequest Username and password

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to login to this form using Scrapy shell. But I am not sure if I am using the right name for the form field.

Get token works

```
token = response.css("form input[name=_csrf_token]::attr(value)").extract_first()
```

this is the call I am using

```
FormRequest.from_response(response,formdata={'_csrf_token':token,'email':'Somepassword','password':'Someemail@gmail.com'})
```

I tried using the id value, name value, type value and none of them logged me into the site.

Here is username field

```
<div class="g-form-group g-mb-3">
<label class="g-form-label g-form-label--small" for="login-form_email">Email Address</label>
<input class="g-form-input" id="login-form_email" name="login[email]" type="email"></div>
```

This is the password field

```
<div class="g-form-group g-mb-3">
<label class="g-form-label g-form-label--small" for="login-form_password">Password</label>
<input class="g-form-input" id="login-form_password" name="login[password]" type="password">
</div>
```

I dont get an error. The post happens but when I try to view(response) I get the login page so I have not logged in into the site. How do I correct my request to login to site and validate i have successfully logged in?

The site I am trying to log into is this one if it is needed

https://auth.pff.com/